# doubt about, show that space metric is a category

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, category-theory, solution-verification

I'll show that space metric is a category.

**Proof.** Let $\mathfrak{G}$-structure and $\mathbb{X}=(X,d_{X})$ and $\mathbb{Y}=(Y,d_{Y})$ a space metrics, elements of $\mathfrak{G}$.
let the continuous functions be the elements of Mor $Mor_{\mathfrak{G}}(\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Y})$.

I should show axiom of morphism:

**Mor 1** Let $\mathbb{X}=(X,d_{X})$ , $\mathbb{Y}=(Y,d_{Y})$ and $\mathbb{Z}=(Z,d_{Z})$ spaces metric. if $f\in Mor_{\mathfrak{G}}(\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Y})$ and $g\in Mor_{\mathfrak{G}}(\mathbb{Y},\mathbb{Z})$. Suppose that $f:(X,d_{X}) \rightarrow (Y,d_{Y})$ is continuous at $a\in X$ and g is continuous at $f(a)$.

Let $\varepsilon>0 $, as $g$ is continuos at $f(a)$, there exist $\beta>0$ such that $d_{Z}(g(f(x)),g(f(a))<\varepsilon$ if $d_{Y}(f(x),f(a))<\beta$. Again $f$ is continuous at $a$, there exist $\delta>0$ such that $d_{Y}(f(x),f(a))<\beta$ if $d_{X}(x,a)<\delta$.

Hence $d_{Z}(g(f(x)),g(f(a))<\varepsilon$ if $d_{X}(x,a)<\delta$, which show that $gof$ is continuous.
Hence $gof\in Mor_{\mathfrak{G}}(\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Z})$.

**Mor 2**.Let $f\in (X,d_{X})\rightarrow (X,d_{X})$- such that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$ and I'll show that $f$ is continuous in $a\in X$.

Let $\varepsilon >0$, there exist $\delta=\varepsilon $, such that $d_{X}(x,a)<\delta$ implies $d_{X}(f(x),a)<\varepsilon$.

Hence  $f\in Mor_{\mathfrak{G}}(\mathbb{X},\mathbb{X})$.

Hence $\mathfrak{G}$ is a category.

I am not sure if I am proving the necessary axioms, I have had doubt if it is time to prove the associative property, excuse my English.

Comment: Yes, that looks fine. All that’s left is to prove the associativity and identity properties, which are quite immediate in this case.

Comment: Hi, @KevinArlin I thought that in $Mor2 $ I prove identity property.

Comment: By "the identity property" I mean that $\mathrm{id}_X$ satisfies the conditions $\mathrm{id}_X\circ f=f$ and $g\circ \mathrm{id}_X=g$ for all $f$ and $g$. Of course this is quite obvious since this category is built out of ordinary functions, but in general it needs to be proven.

Comment: It looks fine, but because you chose the morphisms to be continuous functions, what you have proved is that metrizable topological spaces form a category. The morphisms usually associated to metric spaces are continuous functions that do not increase distance [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_metric_spaces).

Comment: Excuse me, @KevinArlin, 
In this case, the associative property and the identity function can be concluded by set theory properties?

Comment: @hJulian Yes, precisely. It’s perfectly reasonable to define a category of sets to be a collection of maps of sets closed under composition and containing the identity functions, since then the properties follow from elementary set theory.